# How to compute weighted mean of rasters using overlay?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I'm trying to learn how to use function overlay from package raster. When messing with the function to understand it better, I came across this problem. Why don't those two lines give the same result? What would be the correct way of using overlay to get the result of the approach without overlay?

```
library(raster)

# Create rasters

s <- raster(nrow = 45, ncol = 90)
s[] <- 0

r <- stack( mget( rep( "s" , 12 )))
r[] <- runif(ncell(r)*12, 0, 500)

w <- stack( mget( rep( "s" , 12 )))
w[] <- runif(ncell(r)*12, 0, 1)

# Get weighted average 

# without overlay

raster::weighted.mean(r, w)

# with overlay

overlay(r, w, fun = raster::weighted.mean)
```

Thanks!